# Get a previous date from current date in Druid SQL

Tags: sql, druid

How to get the date 7 days before from the current date in Druid SQL? I have done similar in Postgres SQL as

```
CURRENT_DATE - interval '7 day'
```

I need to do the same in Druid SQL query

Comment: I'd try `CURRENT_DATE - interval '7' day`, the ANSI SQL way. (Doesn't this work in Postgresql as well?)

Comment: Did you try what I suggested?

Comment: What your question mean? Do you need to get date value before 7 days, or retrieve records before 7 days from datasource?

Comment: Yes, to get the date value before 7 days from current date

Answer (score 1):

you can just use the timestampadd function like this: `TIMESTAMPADD(DAY, -7, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)` and you can use it within the where clause of a select statement to display records greater than or equal to 7 days as like this:
 `select * from "testdatasource"  WHERE "__time" >= TIMESTAMPADD(DAY, -7, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)`

In case you want to round it to midnight then you can nest it with date_trunc function as follows:
 `DATE_TRUNC('DAY', TIMESTAMPADD(DAY, -7, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))`

Answer (score 0):

Use `timestamp_expr { + | - } <interval_expr>` or `TIME_SHIFT(<timestamp_expr>, <period>, <step>, [<timezone>])` - see the docs at https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/querying/sql.html#time-functions which also explain the difference between the two.