# How to implement the DATE_PART function of Postgres in Druid sql?

Tags: sql, druid

I have a sql query that I use to do some modification on time series data. Here is my sql below (This is based on Postgres. I am just highlighting the date modification part)

```
## 6 days interval
"date_trunc('month', created_at) + (date_part('day', created_at)::int - 1) / 6 * interval '6 day'"

## 10 min interval
"date_trunc('hour', created_at) + date_part('minute', created_at)::int / 10 * interval '10 min'"
```

This works fine but I can't replicate the `date_part` function in Druid. I looked up the documentation of Druid and found some related functions like

`EXTRACT(unit FROM timestamp_expr)`

`TIMESTAMPADD(unit, count, timestamp)`

`TIME_SHIFT(timestamp_expr, period, step, [timezone])`

I also looked up in stack overflow and I found an example for time truncation and  extraction

https://stackoverflow.com/a/65913014/5550284

https://stackoverflow.com/a/65075393/5550284

I tried doing something like below

```
SELECT (date_trunc('hour', __time) + EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM __time) / 5)
```

But this gives me some weird result. I still can't connect the truncation with the specific extraction at n intervals. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

**Add 6 Days**

& retain time of day

```
"expression": "timestamp_shift(created_at, 'P6D', 1, 'UTC')"
```

& set time of day to midnight (truncate to day)

```
"expression": "timestamp_floor(timestamp_shift(created_at, 'P6D', 1, 'UTC'), 'P1D', null, 'UTC')"
```

**Add 6 Minutes**

```
"expression": "timestamp_shift(created_at, 'PT6M', 1, 'UTC')"
```

Comment: Hi, Sorry for the late reply. My apologies! I tried your code but I can't quite figure out how do I exactly use it. I tried doing this `SELECT DATE_TRUNC('DAY', timestamp_floor(timestamp_shift(__time, 'P6D', 1, 'UTC'), 'P1D', null, 'UTC'))` but this isn't working. Maybe I interpreted your answer wrong. Can you clarify?

Comment: Don't use date_trunc() start at timestamp_floor(

Comment: Sorry I didn't quite get you. Are you suggesting to not use `DATE_TRUNC` at all? Perhaps it will be more clear if you could just edit your answer to give an example sql query. That will help a lot.

Comment: It is my understanding that date_trunc is a Postgres function and not supported in Druid, the timestamp_floor() function is the the equivalent `timestamp_floor(created_at,'P1D','null,'UTC')`  is the closest thing to `trunc_date('day',created_at)` nb **P1D** is "period one day"